# IEqualityComparer for class with many properties neither unique value

Tags: linq, entity, compare, iequalitycomparer, icomparer

How do implementation for `IEqualityComparer` for this class?

The ID property is not unique. Neither properties has unique values.

The entity has 7 properties.

```
[Serializable()]
public class ServidorSeleccionadoDto
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string IP { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Entorno { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()] // [XmlIgnore()]
    public string Habilitado { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Tipo { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public int IdGrupo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your object has an ID field.  If this is unique to each object then you would only need to compare on that property.

```
public Boolean Equals(ServidorSeleccionadoDto obj)
{
   return this.ID == obj.ID;
}
```

Note:  This would only work if ID is unique.

---

If the ID property is not unique you will need to compare all your objects properties.

```
public Boolean Equals(ServidorSeleccionadoDto obj)
{
    return this.ID == obj.ID && 
           this.Nombre.Equals(obj.Nombre) && 
           ... etc
}
```

Comment: Maybe using reflection for compare all properties ?